# Get count of available monitors

Tags: c#, uwp, multiple-monitors

I'm writing a UWP app that needs to span several monitors. As part of that requirement, I naturally need to know how many monitors or display devices are currently connected to the machine. This is surprisingly hard to do well in UWP. These are the approaches I've tried so far, which don't work or are limited:

1. Pre-UWP, I would use the `Screen.AllScreens` property from `System.Windows.Forms`, even if it meant importing the WinForms DLL to a WPF app. This is, unfortunately, not an option in UWP any more.
2. Use WMI to access the `Win32_Desktopmonitor` class for that information - again, locked in UWP.
3. Look for it in the registry - the same.
4. Write an external non-UWP utility to retrieve that information, using an AppService to communicate between the UWP and non-UWP app. This seems like an exceedingly complex operation for this requirement.
5. Use the native UWP approach, using `ProjectionManager.GetDeviceSelector()` to get an AQS query which is then passed to `DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync` to get the monitor count. This *works*, but is **exceedingly slow**. It can take it 3-5 seconds to query on my high-end laptop with 4 displays (laptop display, two external monitors an WiDi connection that's not even enabled).

For now, I'm using option #5, the native UWP way. But I would like to know if there's anything simpler I'm missing here, which would allow me to retrieve the number of monitors quicker.

Comment: You could look at using the user32 lib in windows : http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.EnumDisplayMonitors

Comment: Hey, that actually *worked*! I was sure it won't, because other Win32 functions like SetWindowPos don't work under UWP, but this one did! 
Write it up as an answer and I'll gladly accept it.

Comment: Glad i could help :) 
I thought you could use the SetWindowPos for wpf you just had to get the actuall window pointer first from the wpf window ?

Comment: This isn't WPF, so SetWindowPos doesn't work from within UWP. You can get the window handle with some interop magic, but no SetWindowPos.

Comment: UWP encompasses more than just your desktop PC. What does a "monitor" even mean in HoloLens?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to P/Invoke into a `User32` API (or any other unsupported API) *might* work today, but it is not supported by Microsoft, can't be submitted to the Windows Store, and might stop working with a future Windows Update. You should never rely on unsupported functionality on your apps.

UWP currently doesn't have great support for multiple screens or windows, but if your app is Destkop-only you could use a [Desktop Bridge component](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/projects/campaigns/application-development) to find out how many monitors you have, and to position any legacy WinForms / WFP windows.

But you probably can't use a Desktop Bridge component to size or move your UWP windows (a lot of `User32` APIs will just fail).

Answer (score 0):

I would look at Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ProjectionManager.GetDeviceSelector()

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.projectionmanager

I use the ProjectionManager in a UWP project currently to interact with a secondary screen and my app is Windows Store compatible.

Comment: I've mentioned this API in my question, bullet #5, and explained its drawbacks.

Answer (score 0):

For  the native UWP approach (#5), I took a look at the query string, it is something like:

```
"(System.Devices.DevObjectType:=5 AND System.Devices.Aep.ProtocolId:=\"{XXXX}\" AND System.Devices.WiFiDirect.Services:~=\"Miracast\") OR(System.Devices.DevObjectType:=8 AND System.Devices.InterfaceClassGuid:=\"{XXXX}\" AND System.Devices.InterfaceEnabled:=System.StructuredQueryType.Boolean#True)"
```

If I remove the part before "OR", then it doesn't take 5 seconds anymore! I believe the first part is to get wifi devices, which I don't care in my project. So, a solution is to just use the query after "OR" to pass into FindAllAsync() and get the local devices.